# Used heap size increasing continuously

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2, heap-memory

I have JSF web application. I'm using JSF 2.1.9, Hibernate 4.1.4, GlassFish 3.1.2, PrimeFaces 3.4.1. The problem is, used heap size is increasing slowly and after 2-3 days reaches max heap size. Then I must restart GlassFish.

Heap dumps:

At the beginning, i clicked all web pages in application and used heap size was 100 MB:

[image: heapdumpbefore]

A fter 1-2 days, used heap size is increased to 300 MB (same web pages used during this time):

[image: heapdump after]

I took screenshot of most used classes in heap.

In `char[]` class instances, there are too much SQL query string like that:
[image: heapdump char]

Maybe there is not only one problem but I might start to solve from this one. In my web pages, I generally select some objects from database and render it. here are some beans:
images (index controller):

```
@Named("indexController")  
@SessionScoped  
public class IndexController implements Serializable {  
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("imagePU");  

    public List<Image> getImages() {  
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();  
        List<Image> result;  
        try {  
            EntityTransaction entr = em.getTransaction();  
            boolean committed = false;  
            entr.begin();  
            try {  
                Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Image i ORDER BY i.imageId DESC").setMaxResults(12);  
                result = query.getResultList();  
                entr.commit();  
                committed = true;  
            } finally {  
                if (!committed) {  
                    entr.rollback();  
                }  
            }  
        } finally {  
            em.close();  
        }  
        return result;  
    }  
}
```

Tagged images:

```
@Named("galleryBean")  
@SessionScoped  
public class GalleryBean implements Serializable {  

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("imagePU");  

    public List<TaggedImage> getTaggedImages() {  
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();  
        List<TaggedImage> result;  
        try {  
            EntityTransaction entr = em.getTransaction();  
            boolean committed = false;  
            entr.begin();  
            try {  
                Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT ti FROM TaggedImage ti GROUP BY ti.tag ORDER BY ti.taggedImagesId DESC");  
                result = query.getResultList();  
                entr.commit();  
                committed = true;  
            } finally {  
                if (!committed) {  
                    entr.rollback();  
                }  
            }  
        } finally {  
            em.close();  
        }  
        return result;  
    }  
}
```

By the way, I should not perform business logic in getters, but I think it is not the main reason of my problem. I need help and some advices. I can provide more information if needed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with JSF pages once and after a lot of research turned out the problem was number of views which JSF was keeping in session. Not sure if this is the problem in your case but have a look at [this](http://gopinathb4u.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/how-to-configure-number-of-views-in-session-perfomance-tuning-in-jsf/) to configure number of views. Hope this helps.

Comment: Session timeout is 5 minutes. After 5 minutes, these all have to be released from heap right ? I'm testing this application with only 1 active user

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, however you are using session scope backing beans and based on the snippets above, could really be request scoped beans as i dont really see much in them that needs to be session saved.  I would also look at using perhaps a view scope if it is available and restructure the bean so you could benefit from not having to make multiple calls to the database, as jsf is notorious for calling backing beans multiple times, like so.

```
@Named("galleryBean")  
@RequestScoped  // or @ViewScoped
public class GalleryBean implements Serializable {  

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("imagePU");  

    private List<TaggedImage> images = null;

    public List<TaggedImage> getTaggedImages() {  
        if (this.images != null) {
            return this.images;
        }
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();  
        try {  
            EntityTransaction entr = em.getTransaction();  
            boolean committed = false;  
            entr.begin();  
            try {  
                Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT ti FROM TaggedImage ti GROUP BY ti.tag ORDER BY ti.taggedImagesId DESC");  
                images = query.getResultList();  
                entr.commit();  
                committed = true;  
            } finally {  
                if (!committed) {  
                    entr.rollback();  
                }  
            }  
        } finally {  
            em.close();  
        }  
        return images;  
    }  
}
```

Better yet you would separate out the actual fetching of the TaggedImage from the database and put it somewhere it is called as part of the bean construction phase with a @PostConstruct or @URLAction if using pretty faces and getTaggedImages() really just becomes another getter/setter

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your example code, I needed it. And I know that actually I don't need session scoped beans at this time but I think these all other performance optimisation points, not main reason. After sessions timed out, everything have to be released from heap related to sessions.